# Incorporate dropdown list of nodes into a webform to link webform results to said content

Tags: 7, webforms

I am trying to link the results from a webform comment survey to content that was previously generated within a site so that the webform_submissions table in the database shows the node those answers are attached to.

I am planning to use a "node reference" dropdown to the content type I need, but that's as far as I've gone.

Any ideas or suggestions are most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own predefined lists by using the webform_webform_select_options_info() hook.

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_webform_select_options_info().
*/
function yourmodule_webform_select_options_info() {
  $items = array();
  $items['contentchoice'] = array(
    'title' => t('Content Choice'),
    'options callback' => 'webform_options_yournodes',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Then generate your list of nodes using

```
/**
* Webform options info callback.
*/
function webform_options_yournodes() {
  $mynodes = array(
  //build your array up here
  );
  return $mynodes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to webform a select options widget. Then in your implementation of hook_form_alter

```
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'your_webform_name') {
        $nodes = array();
        /*The WHERE section in the query needs to be adjusted to meet your requirements or removed at all if you need to have all nodes in the dropdown*/
        $results = db_query('SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE type=:type', array(':type' => 'article'));
        foreach($results as $result) {
            $nodes[$result->nid] = $result->title;
        }
        $form['submitted']['your_select_widget_name']['#options'] = $nodes;
    }
}
```

I assumed that you use D7. For D6 there might be slight differences in the code.

Comment: I'm on D6, but it's my fault not having mentioned it. Thanx Alex. :)